# Attributes and scope

Tags: jsp, attributes, scope

I started learning JSP recently.

After learning the different JSP elements and the `pageContext` implicit object, I have one confusion. The `pageContext` object has the `removeAttribute()` method to remove attributes.
Can this removed attributes be set using JSP directives or only JSP actions?

Also, what is the default scope of JSP directive attributes?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget about JSP actions. Just as scriptlets, they should not be usd anymore. Learn how JSP tags work, and learn the JSTL (JSP Standard Tag Library). A page-scope attribute is typically set using the JSTL tags:

```
<c:set value="${someBean.someValue}" var="attribute1" />
```

or

```
<fmt:message key="some.message.key" var="attribute2" />
```

for example.

Comment: Thanks !!!
And if i do use directives, can i use the scope attribute with them ??

Comment: Yes, but you'd better forget about them.